# Квадраты вместо русских букв в lua

Tags: lua, roblox

Я так сказать, пишу читы для игр на платформе roblox, в которой используется язык программирования  "lua", и когда писал скрипт, то решил сделать русификацию для него, следовательно перевёл все фразы на русский язык, и при тесте увидел такой результат[image: Сама проблема], кто ни-будь может подсказать как решить эту проблему пожалуйста?

Comment: пиши файлы русификации в той кодировке, в которой понимает игра, чаще всего это utf-8 без bom

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить кодировку текста при помощи библиотеки encoding

```lua
local encoding = require 'encoding'
local u8 = encoding.UTF8

local text = u8'текст' -- Перевод в кодировку UTF8
local text = u8:decode('текст') -- Перевод в кодировку CP1251 (кириллица)
```

Также необходимо указать стандартную кодировку, например кириллицу.

```
encoding.default = 'CP1251'
```

Возможно проблема с шрифтом и он не имеет кириллические символы.